# Gitlab SonarQube Pipeline Notification e-mail

Tags: sonarqube, gitlab, devops

I'm trying hard to understand where to put the e-mail recipient when pipeline successes. 
According to this :
https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin

```
mvn --batch-mode verify sonar:sonar
      -Dsonar.gitlab.api_version=v4
      -Dsonar.host.url=http://<your_sonar_url>:9000
      -Dsonar.login=<your_sonar_login>
      -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview
      -Dsonar.gitlab.commit_sha=$CI_COMMIT_SHA
      -Dsonar.gitlab.ref_name=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
      -Dsonar.gitlab.project_id=$CI_PROJECT_ID
      -Dsonar.gitlab.url=http://<your_gitlab_url>
      -Dsonar.gitlab.user_token=<your_user_token>
```

I've tried to add -Dsonar.gitlab.ref_name=team@team.com for example. Not sure if that is the correct way.

At the moment only the person who runs the pipeline gets a notification.
The only setting I see in this the documentation is : 
Warning, master must have a codequality.json, use commit-status for notification mode (not mandatory)

Comment: If you look [here](https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin/blob/983b9c403207dd679ca2e4552ca655bb70d72e80/src/main/java/com/talanlabs/sonar/plugins/gitlab/GitLabPlugin.java) ref_name is "The commit revision for which project is built".

Answer (score 0):

@Danny , In gitlab you can create a group with your team members. Create project under that group. So whenever pipeline fails or succeeds email will be sent to the entire group.